# How can I use VsCode Remote on a team?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I work on a team of software engineers who support a suite of Python services. We use docker orchestrate those services in development. For example, I might edit code in one service, and when I save a change, the changes are reflected in the relevant container via a bind mount, then the service gets inotify'd of the change and hot-reloads. The configuration for these docker containers are checked into git and shared across the team. This way, none of the engineers are required to install  Python or any of the required packages on their workstations, and we can be sure that the environment in which software is built closely mirrors production.

It appears that VsCode does not support this approach to development gracefully. Since none of the dependencies are installed on engineers' workstations, the Python extension shows tons of false-positive import errors. We can't make use of linting, and we can't use VsCode's debugging or build features.

At first glance, it would appear that [VsCode Remote](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) is intended to solve these problems, but upon closer inspection, it creates a whole suite of new problems. Since many extensions have to be installed inside the container, engineers either lose the ability to customize their editors or must reconfigure their editors every time a container is restarted. The docs suggest using a volume to persist the configs, but there doesn't appear to be any way to sync them to or from a local directory. There appears to be no support for a codebase that produces multiple containers. And finally, using the Remote pack would require us to add special VsCode-related config to our shared dockerfiles, and some of the members of the team use other editors. In short, it turns an individual concern (editor configuration) into a team concern.

Am I missing something here? Is there any supported way to work in a containerized development environment with VsCode when the container configurations are maintained as a team? I feel like I can't be the only person who has this problem.

Comment: I'm impressed, and I wish I had the expertise to help.  There are *so* many ways for this to be off-topic for Stack Overflow; in my opinion, you've avoided them all.  I think this is *better* suited to a VS support site, but SO is a reasonable additional chance for support.

Comment: Thanks @Prune! This question definitely seemed a little odd for SO to me too, but according to the [VsCode Python extension README](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python#questions-issues-feature-requests-and-contributions), they appear to prefer SO for questions and issues only for bugs and feature requests. So here I am ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Perhaps -- but note that Stack Overflow doesn't recognize this site as the official support for VsCode; they're being somewhat presumptive ... but perhaps with justification.

Comment: Most of all, I can see where other SO denizens might scan this post and deem it off-topic.  I hope my comment prompts them to read it in more detail.

Comment: @whereswalden It's quite the setup, but unfortunately I'm not aware of any good way to make it such that you are not sharing your configuration as I don't think a live-shared container across multiple developers is a considered use-case.

Comment: @Prune basically we made SO the place to ask support-like questions for the Python extension because that's where we found users were already doing that before we specified a place to ask such questions.

Comment: @BrettCannon I think there's some confusion here, multiple developers aren't sharing the same container, they're sharing the same dockerfile. We check dockerfiles into our repo and built containers from them locally to create our individual development environments.  It's a fairly common setup for modern dev teams.

Comment: @whereswalden then I'm not understanding now "many extensions have to be installed inside the container, engineers either lose the ability to customize their editors or must reconfigure their editors every time a container is restarted." If you don't commit your `.vscode/settings.json` then you can have a custom configuration. Otherwise the in-preview [settings sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_settings-sync) may help with configuration and customization.

Comment: @BrettCannon the problem comes from the interaction of three factors: that some plugins must be installed in the container, that the dockerfiles are source-controlled and standardized, and that the containers are ephemeral. If any one of those was false, there'd be no problem. For example, if everyone maintained their own dockerfiles, they could put whatever setup in them they want, or if the containers were persistent, then devs would only have to configure their editors once.
Aside from that, as a team we don't want to have to endorse a particular editor to have a reasonable workflow.

Comment: @whereswalden I guess my confusion is coming from why having source-controlled Dockerfiles is an impediment? My understanding is that the Remote - Containers extension uses `docker compose` to layer on the VS Code stuff so there's no editing of the Dockerfile. As for being ephemeral, I could see having to wait for all of that to load up every day being annoying. So at this point I'm afraid I'm out of ideas if these questions don't lead to some magical clarification on my end.

Comment: @BrettCannon Here's an example: (1) boot up my dev environment (docker-compose up), (2) open my vscode workspace in the container, (3) activate and configure all of the plugins that weren't installed in the container, (4) go home for the day and run `docker-compose down`, (5) come back in the next day and run `docker-compose up. None of my plugins are installed or configured anymore, so I have to start over at step 3. I feel like I might be missing something, but this workflow seems untenable.

Comment: @whereswalden so that sounds very specific to the Remote - Containers extension and not Python-specific. I would file an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues to see if they can help.

Comment: @BrettCannon I can do that. I wanted to tag y'all because one way you could solve this issue would be to build remote interpreter capabilities into the Python extension. I know that was an idea you were tossing around for a while and closed in favor of the Remote extensions; I just wanted to provide a data point where remote interpreters solve a problem that Remote extensions don't.

Comment: @whereswalden you are correct we thought about it, but now that the remote extensions exist we won't be doing that as it's a _massive_ thing to undertake for a team of our size.